# JWT Server Authentication Signature validation failed for BOX in PHP

Tags: php, box

**I'm facing the issue with validation of JWT Signature in PHP.
Here is my code**

```
// Create token header as a JSON string
 $header = ["alg" => "RS256",
            "typ" => "JWT", 
            "kid" => "gnkp02u2"];
 $header = json_encode((object) $header);

// Create token payload as a JSON string
$payload = [ 
        "typ" => "jwt",
        "kid" => "gnkp02u2", 
        "iss" => "op63g1amchcxy456oei2tkfk1lg4dbxy",
        "aud" => "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token", 
        "jti" => "4f1g23a12aa854rtyuil",
        "exp" => time() + 30,
        "sub" => "23527187", 
        "box_sub_type" => "enterprise"];
$payload = json_encode((object) $payload);

// Encode Header to Base64Url String
 $base64UrlHeader = str_replace(["+", "/", "="], ["-", "_", ""], 
 base64_encode($header));

// Encode Payload to Base64Url String
$base64UrlPayload = str_replace(["+", "/", "="], ["-", "_", ""], 
base64_encode($payload));

$headerPayload = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload;
//$headerPayload = base64_encode($header) . "." . base64_encode($payload);

// Create Signature Hash
$privateKey = "file://private.key";

try{ 
     $privateKeyResource = openssl_get_privatekey($privateKey, 
"73bed4ee2b994f5fdf0ddef660d8f935");

$result = openssl_sign($headerPayload, $signature, $privateKeyResource, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

if ($result === false)
{
    var_dump($result);
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generate signature: ".implode("\n", getOpenSSLErrors()));
}

$signatureEncoded = base64_encode($signature);

$jwt = "$base64UrlHeader.$base64UrlPayload.$signatureEncoded";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
print_r( $jwt );`
```

**And it generates**

`eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Imdua3AwMnUyIn0.eyJ0eXAiOiJqd3QiLCJraWQiOiJnbmtwMDJ1MiIsImlzcyI6Im9wNjNnMWFtY2hjeHk0NTZvZWkydGtmazFsZzRkYnh5IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2FwaS5ib3guY29tXC9vYXV0aDJcL3Rva2VuIiwianRpIjoiNGYxZzIzYTEyYWE4NTRydHl1aWwiLCJleHAiOjE1MjIwODI5OTUsInN1YiI6IjIzNTI3MTg3IiwiYm94X3N1Yl90eXBlIjoiZW50ZXJwcmlzZSJ9.JMH1sXHrAsT9dURJF/5sOgl2k+qFX/wiqwER4RZwdtxLkLDXDJTzFGZuLPW8JMKqdzntc9hIdc/RHQOla2mi4s1WiGEj/9T1gBPWhjTd4kiZgEenLsZUuLFG77wlzdNPQnm3jON7kM08EfQZU+YYhGDF6JVJ2yH31zkJZqucdbg9Ne43OYPMKEmfa1bKJ3/QmLZXHIEgTYGhh78RsbzViJq3wCqWtUOmksDxCz7/400ZDrmQRH1JIEJW1W6A1oAjPEJVSTniw6a60VVTDXW3WUI0TN68CG5PuNzTXEJcBgnfr1J4yVWeat4rArEyOFsLoyOgBSIu0IHcMRo/V4Md4w==`

**And I'm using this assertion in curl like this**

`$ curl https://api.box.com/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&client_id=op63g1amchcxy456oei2tkfk1lg4dbxy&client_secret=R7MGxLa7dAZfz5YbXMMPf6a6m8OcYZ2K&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Imdua3AwMnUyIn0.eyJ0eXAiOiJqd3QiLCJraWQiOiJnbmtwMDJ1MiIsImlzcyI6Im9wNjNnMWFtY2hjeHk0NTZvZWkydGtmazFsZzRkYnh5IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2FwaS5ib3guY29tXC9vYXV0aDJcL3Rva2VuIiwianRpIjoiNGYxZzIzYTEyYWE4NTRydHl1aWwiLCJleHAiOjE1MjIwODI5OTUsInN1YiI6IjIzNTI3MTg3IiwiYm94X3N1Yl90eXBlIjoiZW50ZXJwcmlzZSJ9.JMH1sXHrAsT9dURJF/5sOgl2k+qFX/wiqwER4RZwdtxLkLDXDJTzFGZuLPW8JMKqdzntc9hIdc/RHQOla2mi4s1WiGEj/9T1gBPWhjTd4kiZgEenLsZUuLFG77wlzdNPQnm3jON7kM08EfQZU+YYhGDF6JVJ2yH31zkJZqucdbg9Ne43OYPMKEmfa1bKJ3/QmLZXHIEgTYGhh78RsbzViJq3wCqWtUOmksDxCz7/400ZDrmQRH1JIEJW1W6A1oAjPEJVSTniw6a60VVTDXW3WUI0TN68CG5PuNzTXEJcBgnfr1J4yVWeat4rArEyOFsLoyOgBSIu0IHcMRo/V4Md4w==' -X POST`

**And in response I'm getting this error**

`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Signature verification error. The public key identified by \"kid\" must correspond to the private key used for signing."}`

**Even kid is given and correct
I don't know what I'm doing wrong**

Comment: 1. Turn the url-safe base64 encoding into a function. 2. Use it on the signature portion of your token as well.

Comment: I'm unable to understand point 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved Box JWT Token issue by using https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt repository, and this is working fine.

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class BoxApi
{
    public $authorize_url = 'https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize';
    public $token_url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token';
    public $api_url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0';
    public $upload_url = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0';
    public $access_token;
    public $filename;
    public $passPhrase;
    public $clientId;
    public $clientSecret;
    public $accessType;
    public $accessTypeId;
    public $publicKeyId;

    public function __construct($filename, $passPhrase, $clientId, $clientSecret, $accessType = "enterprise", $accessTypeId, $publicKeyId)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->passPhrase = $passPhrase;
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
        $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
        $this->accessType = $accessType;
        $this->accessTypeId = $accessTypeId;
        $this->publicKeyId = $publicKeyId;
        self::getAccessToken();
    }

    /* Get AccessToken by JWT*/

    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        $private_key_file = $this->filename;
        $fp = fopen ($private_key_file, "r");
        if (!$fp)
        {
            die("Unable to open file");
        }

        $raw_key_data = fread ($fp, filesize ($private_key_file));
        fclose ($fp);

        $privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey($raw_key_data , $this->passPhrase);

        define("FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY", $privateKey);
        $token = array(
            "iss" => $this->clientId,
            "aud" => "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token",
            "jti" => sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
                mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
                mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
                mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
                mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
                mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
            ),
            "exp" => time() + 30,
            "sub" => $this->accessTypeId,
            "box_sub_type" => $this->accessType
        );

        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY, 'RS256', $this->publicKeyId);

        $params = 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&client_id=' . $this->clientId . '&client_secret=' . $this->clientSecret . '&assertion=' . $jwt;
        $token = json_decode(self::httpClient("POST", $this->token_url, $params), true);
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($token);
        print "</pre>";
        $this->access_token = $token["access_token"];
    }

    /* Sets the required before biulding the query */

    private function set_opts(array $opts)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('access_token', $opts)) {
            $opts['access_token'] = $this->access_token;
        }
        return $opts;
    }

    /* Builds the URL for the call */

    private function build_url($api_func, array $opts = array(), $url = null)
    {
        print "build uri";
        $opts = $this->set_opts($opts);
        if (isset($url)) {
            $base = $url . $api_func . '?';
        } else {
            $base = $this->api_url . $api_func . '?';
        }
        $query_string = http_build_query($opts);
        $base = $base . $query_string;
        return $base;
    }

    /* Uploads a file */

    public function put_file($filename, $parent_id)
    {
        $file = defined('PHP_MAJOR_VERSION') && PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 5 ? new CurlFile(realpath($filename)) : '@/' . realpath($filename);
        $url = $this->build_url('/files/content', array(), $this->upload_url);
        $params = array('filename' => $file, 'name' => basename($filename), 'parent_id' => $parent_id, 'access_token' => $this->access_token);
        return json_decode($this->httpClient("post", $url, $params), true);
    }

    /* Create a new folder */
    public function create_folder($name, $parent_id)
    {
        $url = $this->build_url("/folders");
        $params = array('name' => $name, 'parent' => array('id' => $parent_id));
        return json_decode($this->httpClient("post", $url, json_encode($params)), true);
    }

    /* Modifies the folder details as per the api */
    public function update_folder($folder, array $params)
    {
        $url = $this->build_url("/folders/$folder");
        return json_decode($this->httpClient("put", $url, $params), true);
    }

    /* Shares a folder */
    public function share_folder($folder, array $params)
    {
        $url = $this->build_url("/folders/$folder");
        return json_decode($this->httpClient("put", $url, $params), true);
    }

    /* Shares a file */
    public function share_file($file, array $params)
    {
        $url = $this->build_url("/files/$file");
        return json_decode($this->httpClient("put", $url, $params), true);
    }

    /* Curl Api calls */
    private static function httpClient($method, $url, $params = null)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if (strcasecmp($method, "POST") == 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        } elseif (strcasecmp($method, "PUT") == 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
        } elseif (strcasecmp($method, "DELETE") == 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
        }
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}

?>
```